# Google Apps Directory Sync, unique identifier and directory api

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am using Google Apps Directory Sync to provision users into Google Apps from an LDAP directory.  We have specified a unique identifier attribute from our directory to detect and track user renames.  The attribute values are eight-character strings, and not, say, the LDAP objectID.  Example: "bcdf1234".

When retrieving users from the Directory API, I am not finding our unique identifier value in the response.  Is there a way to get the Directory API to return our unique identifier?

Related: is our unique identifier displayed anywhere in the Admin Console when viewing a user?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a current GADS implementation to confirm but I remember that GADS used a local database on the machine it was installed on. There was an internal table there of the unique ids on the customer side of GADS, mapping them to the user account ids on the Google side.

So to answer your question: Those customer side ids would not need to be pushed up to Google so they will not be able to be retrieved via the Directory API.

Options:

1. You could perhaps push them up to the Google side with GADS itself if you mapped them to a Google side attribute.
2. You could also sync them up to Google via the Directory API itself by updating the [user resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource) with say an `externalId` if you knew the current user id (email address) to get and update.